# How to check Google token after login?

Tags: php

I would like to know to retrieve token after login? I am using this code but retrieve an error

```
$idToken = 'xxxxxxx';

$auth = new Google\Auth\AccessToken();
$info = $auth->verify($idToken, [
  'certsLocation' => Google\Auth\AccessToken::IAP_CERT_URL,
  'throwException' => true,
]);

if ($audience != $info['aud'] ?? '') {
    throw new Exception(sprintf(
        'Audience %s did not match expected %s', $info['aud'], $audience
    ));
}
```

Here is the error I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Please require
> kelvinmo/simplejwt ^0.2 to use this utility. in
> /home/admin/public_html/dsimlife.com/vendor/google/auth/src/AccessToken.php:412
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/admin/public_html/dsimlife.com/vendor/google/auth/src/AccessToken.php(196):
> Google\Auth\AccessToken->checkSimpleJwt() #1
> /home/admin/public_html/dsimlife.com/vendor/google/auth/src/AccessToken.php(136):
> Google\Auth\AccessToken->verifyEs256(123, Array, NULL, NULL) #2
> /home/admin/public_html/dsimlife.com/googlecheck.php(25):
> Google\Auth\AccessToken->verify(123, Array) #3 {main} thrown in
> /home/admin/public_html/dsimlife.com/vendor/google/auth/src/AccessToken.php
> on line 412

Answer (score 0):

The Google auth library requires [kelvinmo/simplejwt](https://github.com/kelvinmo/simplejwt) for this method. Simply require this library in your project and it should be working:

```
composer require kelvinmo/simplejwt ^0.2
```

See also https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php/issues/271 why they didn't include it in their library requirements (as you would have expected).